# Redirect to edit path using drop down and Jquery in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a select drop down of items. When the user selects and item I need to redirect to edit_item_path for the item_id. e.g. If user selects and item with id =5 I need to redirect to items/5/edit path

How to do this in rails 3 and jquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets say that your dropdown looks like this:

```
<select id="editable_pages">
  <option value="1">Edit 1</option>
  <option value="2">Edit 2</option>
</select>
```

in that case following jquery snippet should works:

```
$('#editable_pages').change(function() {
    window.location = "items/+ $(this).find(":selected").text() +/edit";
});
```

Nicer solution is to use rails route helpers. To do that you could add a html5 data attribute with url to each options, eg:

```
<option value="1" data-edit-url="<%= edit_item_url(1) %>">Edit 1</option>

$('#editable_pages').change(function() {
    window.location = $(this).find(":selected").data('edit-url');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this...

```
<% @item_paths = {""=>"", "Item 5" => edit_item_path(5), "Item 4" => edit_item_path(4)}%>
<%= select_tag :edit_item, options_for_select(@item_paths)%>

<script type="text/javascript">
      $('#edit_item').change(function() {
      window.location = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
      });
 </script>
```