# Using dropdown selector to change paths in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, drop-down-menu, routes

I have a dropdown selector next to a search box in my navigation bar.

```
<select>
    <option> All </option>
    <option> Ask </option>
    <option> Offer </option>
</select>



<form class="navbar-form navbar-right">

      <%= form_tag(i_want_to_choose_this_path, :method => :get) do %>
          <%= text_field_tag :search, nil,
                             {:id => "search-query-2", :placeholder => "Search favors..."} %>
          <%= hidden_field_tag :use_keywords, "true" %>
          <%= hidden_field_tag :wide_search, "true" %>
      <% end %>
  </form>
```

How can I use the selected option to change the path the search form will route to, to either asks_path, offers_path or all_path? The options are just words that relate to the paths I want to choose. They do not exist in any models. I looked at category_select, but it seems to require that my options are related to a model, which they don't, and I'm not sure how they would, because the paths point to different models.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using selected option from dropdown to select path in Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24153189/using-selected-option-from-dropdown-to-select-path-in-rails)

Comment: I can't find an answer to this anywhere on the internet. Thought it sounded pretty simple. Am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: This [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12413781/redirect-to-edit-path-using-drop-down-and-jquery-in-rails) should help you.